# How to Create a Unique One Time Reset Password Link in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, reset-password

I have **Django** website which users can register and login with their phone number.
Recently I decide to add a **recover password with phone number** part to my site,I read [Authentication Views in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) which users can reset their password by sending them an email but first of all it use email to reset password and second it use django built-in views, but I want a function in my view which generate a unique one time reset password link then I send this link to them with my sms api so they can reset their password using this link.
So how can I generate reset password link in a secure way?
the only idea that I've got is to implement a model which store a random string with OnetoOne relation and use it as a reset password link.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah your solution is good idea, I think
Better implementation of your idea is:

Add following in your settings:

```
JWT_SECRET = SECRET_KEY  # use settings secret key for JWT secret
JWT_ALGORITHM = 'HS256'
JWT_EXP_DELTA_SECONDS = 86400  # token expiring time in seconds let's assign one day
```

and here are the functions to encode and decode the reset token:

```
from your_django_project import settings
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import jwt

def encoded_reset_token(user_id):
    payload = {
        'user_id': user_id,
        'exp': datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=settings.JWT_EXP_DELTA_SECONDS)
    }
    encoded_data = jwt.encode(payload, settings.JWT_SECRET, settings.JWT_ALGORITHM)
    return  encoded_data.decode('utf-8')

def decode_reset_token(reset_token):
    try:
        decoded_data = jwt.decode(reset_token, settings.JWT_SECRET,
                                  algorithms=[settings.JWT_ALGORITHM])
    except (jwt.DecodeError, jwt.ExpiredSignatureError):
        return None  # means expired token

    return decoded_data['user_id']
```

so there is no need to use extra table to store your reset tokens

Comment: Can you explain me how should I implement a path in my urls.py?

Comment: and exactly what link should I send to users to reset their password?
and after they click on the link how it suppose to reset the password?